# How to select the type of time semantics when working with tumbling windows?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on kafka streams windowing , particularly tumbling windows for my use case.

```
TimeWindowedKStream<String, Blob> windowedStreams = groupedStreams
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)));
```

this is a tumbling window for 5 minutes per record key and advances by 5 minutes. For my use case, I want no old message to be dropped and hence I want  it to consider processing time as time semantic.

what is the default behaviour of tumbling window for time semantics, how does I specify in tumbling windows which time semantic to pick ?event time/processing time/ingestion time.

Comment: the same is applicable for all types of windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time semantics are not specified on the window definition, but depend on the configured `TimestampeExtractor`. If you want to switch to processing time semantics, you can set `default.timestamp.extractor` to `WallclockTimestampExtractor.class` in the `KafkaStreams` config.

Compare

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#time
- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#streams-developer-guide-timestamp-extractor

Comment: i could see default configuration for "default.timestamp.extractor" is "TimestampExtractor.class". on reading the documentation of timestamp.extractor, I understood that it extracts the timestamp from the record. Here, i am not setting any configuration while producing.so what is the default timestamp for record ? is it the time when record being generated at producer ?

Comment: As explained in the docs, the default is extractor is ` FailOnInvalidTimestamp.class` that return the embedded record timestamp from the timestamp field. If your topic is configures with `create-time` semantics, this timestamp will be one set by the producer.